# Index on concatenated columns isn't being used on query

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I've created the following index on expression:

```
CREATE INDEX ON administration((client_name || ' - ' || project_name));
```

When I try to execute a query that uses this expression, the result is some slowly. The query is:

```
SELECT client_name || ' - ' || project_name FROM administration WHERE 
(client_name || ' - ' || project_name LIKE 'AT&T%');
```

On `\d administration` I can see:

```
...
"projects_expr_idx" btree (((client_name::text || ' - '::text) || project_name::text))
...
```

But using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on the query, the result doesn't appear to use the index created:

```
                                    QUERY PLAN                                              
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Seq Scan on projects  (cost=0.00..142.40 rows=1 width=32) (actual 
time=0.036..1.874 rows=60 loops=1)
Filter: ((((client_name)::text || ' - '::text) || (project_name)::text) ~~ '%AT&T%'::text)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 3677
Planning time: 0.214 ms
Execution time: 1.889 ms
(5 rows)
```

Am I wrong? Or the query doesn't need to use the index created. Thanks for your help.

Another and last question, supposing that the index is working, this query will use it?

```
SELECT projects 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            CASE
              WHEN left(project_name, 2) = ' -' THEN 
                client_name || project_name 
              ELSE 
                client_name || ' - ' || project_name 
            END AS projects 
        FROM administration) 
    WHERE projects LIKE '%AT&T%' 
    ORDER BY projects ASC 
    LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: Your data may be too small for Postgres to decide to use a an index.  And no, the index will not be used for the last query.

Comment: We have a table that will use the mentioned index and has 100k-200k rows... Using the last query that I shown, the index will be used?

Comment: Depending on your locale (is not C) you might need to use one of those operators class: `text_pattern_ops, varchar_pattern_ops, bpchar_pattern_ops` for regexp to work.

Comment: No index will be used for last query, because you have created an index on (client_name || ' - ' || project_name) but in you last query you are working on  project_name in administration table.